# How to handle events inside a WPF DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, events, custom-controls, datatemplate

I have a custom control which has a dependency property called ViewModel which value is shown inside a `ContentPresenter`. I have a `DataTemplate` for each type of ViewModel. Each template allows the user to make a selection in a different way and I need to handle that selection event in the custom control code behind.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelOne}">

                <!-- how to handle this event? -->
                <ListBox
                    MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelTwo}">

                <!-- this ListBox has another style, but event should
                     be handled the same way -->
                <ListBox
                    MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <!-- more templates here -->

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ViewModel}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Edit:**

Here's the code behind of the custom control with the method I would like to be called when something in the `ListBox` is double clicked:

```
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    // how to attach ListBox MouseDoubleClick event to this method? 
    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DoMagic(((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: got the same issue. Can you post your actual solution?

Answer (score 1):

Are these DataTemplates defined in a resource dictionary?

if so, you can use the [attached behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF).

If they are defined in a MyWindow or a MyUserControl XAML then you can defined them the code behind i.e. `MyWindow.xaml.cs` or `MyUserControl.xaml.cs`

Comment: The DataTemplates are defined in the ResourceDictionary inside the style belonging to the custom control. But if a add an attached behavior that hooks on the `MouseDoubleClick` event, how do I (in the event handler) move the selected item to the custom control code behind?

Comment: `MouseDoubleClick` event of what? `ListBoxItem`? Then you already have selected it isnt it? If you are handling `ListBox.MouseDoubleClickEvent` then using `((ListBox)sender).SelectedItem` will give you all you need.

Comment: Yes, I use the `SelectedItem` of the sender in my code behind. My problem is that the xaml cant find the event handler in code behind. I assume this is because the `DataTemplate` is not directly related to the code behind of the custom control.

Comment: Added some code behind, hopefully this will make the question clearer.